# Android ScrollView flexible look

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a simple question. I use ScrollView container in my application and it works well. But I saw some applications which had more beautiful ScrollView then my application. For example flexible, no fixed regions etc...

Is there any easy way to add this eye-candy function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: please give more info on what you want exactly?

Comment: For example - If I am on the top of ScrollView and I am touching display for shift on the top -> the screen does nothing. But some applications and menus roll down a little bit and then go back. Thank you

Comment: actually that is the default , that always happens with me without adding anything special